# accessing data in table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple tables in a page and I want to manipulate table divisions using jquery,i.e., access specific td, adding a new td to existing tr at a specific location etc.

I have following sample code that is giving "val is undefined" in place of "row1 div1" :(

```
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr id="row1">
            <td id="div1">
                row1 div1

            </td>
            <td id="div2">
                row1  div2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
            <td id="div1">
                row2 div1

            </td>
            <td id="div2">
                row2 div2
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var p = $("#table1#row1#div1").val();
            console.log("val is "+p);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Use $("#div1") or $("table#table1 tr:first-child td:first-child")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want this

`var p = $("#table1 #row1 #div1").text();`

`#table1#row1#div1` looks for 1 element with all of these properties.

`.val()` looks for the value of an element. You want the actual text within it.

Comment: Thanks scott, now I am able to access the component. Also could you please tell me how to enter a new td between div1 and div2 (after checking if div2 exists)?

Comment: Try `$("#table1 #row1 #div1").after('<td>LOL!</td>');`

Comment: `if ($('#table1 #row1 #div1').length > 0) ...`
Will tell you if that div exists

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#row2").append("<td>content</td>");
});
```

What your doing in the code bellow here is selecting #table1 with an id of #row1. I'm not sure if thats what your looking for.

```
var p = $("#table1#row1#div1").val();
```